# Quartz Scheduler not running

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I wanted to post a message after every five seconds in my web app, i am using Quatz to schedule this task. Here's my Code

```
public class InvoiceGenerationSchedular implements ServletContextListener {

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("Listener is off");
}

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    System.out.println("Listener initialized.");

    JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob.class)
            .withIdentity("dummyJobName", "group1").build();
    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName", "group1")
            .withSchedule(

    CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?")).build();

            //schedule it
    Scheduler scheduler;
        try {
            scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();               
            scheduler.start();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

        } catch (SchedulerException e) {                    
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }

}

class HelloJob implements Job
{

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("Hello Quartz!");            
    }   
}}
```

and my web.xml is

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>InvoiceGenerationServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>InvoiceGenerationSchedular</servlet-class>
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>InvoiceGenerationServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/InvoiceGenerationServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  
<listener>
        <listener-class>InvoiceGenerationSchedular</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Now the Problem is every time i run the code it gives me only The output

Listener Initialized

and nothing else , though i wanted it to print "Hello Quartz" after every 5 seconds but it prints nothing. I don't understand why, doesn't give me any exception either. I am very new to Quartz so that's why i don't know how to solve this problem . I of-course googled my problem first but didn't get much answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding forJob(job) in your trigger builder like this -

```
TriggerBuilder
        .newTrigger()
        .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName", "group1")
        .forJob(job)//<--- this line is the new addition
        .withSchedule(
         CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?")).build();
```

Comment: thank u for the answer but i already got my answer . I have posted it , see the answer can u tell me the reason why?

Comment: and thanks , ur answer is working too. However i don't get why it's printing my answer 2 times after 5 seconds and not just one time??

Comment: ok i restarted eclipse and problem went away , though i found my answer but ur answer was correct too.

Comment: Just spent 5 hrs troubleshooting this. The fact that this enormous caveat is not front and center in the getting started guide leaves me in disbelief. Cart before the horse without any doubt.

Answer (score 8):

I can't believe i wasted 2 hours for no reason.
I got the answer , i simply created a separate class of HelloJob in another file and then it worked but it wasn't working when i had the class inside my main class . But i don't understand the reason , what difference did it make??
Can anyone answer this?

Comment: Thank you for your finding. I also spent more than an hour figuring it out. I believe it has something to do with the reflection. Because scheduler uses reflection to create an instance of the job object. If it's an inner class, then reflection doesn't work, my guess.

Comment: If your job class inside main class it must be at public scope

Answer (score -1):

Alternativelly to make it possible using nested class, you had to just declare it as **static**